# Order query by post meta value

Tags: query, author, order

```
      //Displaying latest post per author on front page
  function filter_where($where = '') {
    global $wpdb;
    $where .= " AND vipwp_posts.id = (select id from {$wpdb->prefix}posts p2 where p2.post_status = 'publish' and p2.post_author = {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_author order by p2.post_date desc limit 0,1)";
    return $where;
  }
  add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```

I would like to modify the code above: Is it possible change the order of the record from date by meta_value?

Example:
CHANGE

```
order by p2.post_date
```

TO

```
meta_key='name_key' ORDER BY meta_value
```

---

Thanks, but if I remove post_where do not Displaying latest post per author

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the WordPress Codex:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby

```
function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {
    $orderby_statement = "meta_value DESC";
    return $orderby_statement;
} add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');
```

If you're making the WP_Query yourself you can change the `orderby` parameter to `meta_value`

Take a look here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thanks, buy if I remove post_where do not Displaying latest post per author

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this entirely from the `pre_get_posts` action.  So try removing your `posts_where` filter and replacing it with:

```
function wpa_69199( $query ) {
        set_query_var( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        set_query_var( 'meta_key', 'name_key' ); //field you'd like to order by
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_69199' );
```

Note: there is no conditional logic here and all posts everywhere will be sorted this way.